# Creating a new Nintendo network ID on 3DS with games on it

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, nintendo-network-id

So I got this used 3DS XL at a pawn shop that has a number of different games downloaded on it. They told me when I bought it that the games were tied to the system so not to try to reset it myself or I would lose all the games and the save data.

I recently went to the Nintendo eShop and wanted to download the Pokemon Sun and Moon Demo. When I went to do so it said I needed to link a Nintendo Network ID in order to use this software and prompted me to go to the NNID settings.

When I went to the System Settings and then to the NNID Settings, it said "Hi there, kids! Please have a parent or guardian look at this for you, OK?" then when I hit A (OK) the next screen said "Welcome! You can link a Nintendo Network ID to your system here." The next few screens have info about the NNID and then I reached a screen that had two options; one to link an existing ID and one to create a new ID.

I am assuming that this means that there is not a NNID linked on this 3DS. So what I was wondering is: first off if someone could help me confirm if my assumption is correct or not; and two, if I proceed and create a new NNID on this system, will I lose the games and save data I already have on it?

Comment: Creating a new NNID will make you lose the games on there, unless they are saved on the device itself, like the limited edition 20th anniversary Pokemon 3DS, which had Pokemon Red and Blue pre-installed on them.

Comment: I'm partially curious about how the games got downloaded on the device if there isn't an associated NNID in the eShop already...

Comment: I believe they are saved to the SD card that came with it; is there a way I can find out?

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption of there not being an NNID on the system is correct.

However, you cannot create a new NNID without losing the games and save data.